# Making a Method be triggered when a row is selected in a Table View

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstableview

How would I trigger a Method when a row in a Table View is selected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `NSTableViewDelegate` to control what happens when you use a `NSTableView`. If your relevant view holding the table is named `MyViewController`, your interface (`.h`) file should start like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : NSObject <NSTableViewDelegate> {
```

And then in your implementation (`.m`) file, have this:

```
- (id)init {
     [super init];
     myTableView.delegate = self;
     return self;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldSelectRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
     NSLog(@"%i tapped!", rowIndex);
     return YES;
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether i m doing right or wrong (as there are few confusing tutorials avail on the web) but above solution works for me :)
Thanks !!

Comment: I've upvoted, because this will work but I think the better method to use is `tableViewSelectionDidChange:` since the method you use is really there to ask permission if the selection is allowed to change.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to the [NSTableViewDelegate docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Tasks/UsingTableDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000116-CJBDHFIC).

Comment: NSTableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification?

Comment: That's a notification name (which is why it ends in “Notification”). Observing for the notification is one way, but being the delegate is easier.

Answer (score -5):

Am I missing something?  Just call it in the following delegate method: [didSelectRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Because this is a question whose answer you clearly put no effort into finding whatsoever.

Comment: All of you are wrong. `NSTableView` is for Mac OSX. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is for iOS. I think the person who asked this question asked a good one because its not as straight forward on Mac OS X as it is on iOS.